# How to iterate over the first n elements of a zip lists?

Tags: python

I have a code with a for loop in zip lists.

I'd like to iterate just n elements, I know that in a normal for loop list I will use this:

`itertools.islice`

but I don't know when I use zip lists

This is my full code:

```
from typing import Generator

from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


matchlink2 = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/football/chile/primera-division/results/'

def _get_rows(url: str) -> Generator[dict[str, str], None, None]:
 
    session = HTMLSession()
 
    r = session.get(matchlink2)


    links = r.html.find('a.in-match')

    for link in links:
        match_link = link.attrs['href']


        linked = 'https://www.betexplorer.com' + match_link

        session = HTMLSession()
 
        r = session.get(linked)

        allmatch2 = r.html.find("span.list-breadcrumb__item__in")
        partialresults = r.html.find(".list-details__item__partial")
        finalresults = r.html.find(".list-details__item__score")

        

        for match2, partialres, finalres in zip(allmatch2, partialresults, finalresults):
            match2.text
            partialres.text
            finalres.text
            print(match2.text)
            print(partialres.text)
            print(finalres.text)
            yield {
                "match": match2.text,
                "htftresult": partialres.text,
                "result": finalres.text,
                
            }
```

I tried to use "itertools.islice" but without success.

Thanks for your help

**EDIT:**

I tried Ivan's solution, but I still get all values. This is my updated code:

```
    from typing import Generator
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import islice


matchlink2 = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/football/chile/primera-division/results/'

def _get_rows(url: str) -> Generator[dict[str, str], None, None]:
 
    session = HTMLSession()
 
    r = session.get(matchlink2)


    links = r.html.find('a.in-match')

    for link in links:
        match_link = link.attrs['href']


        linked = 'https://www.betexplorer.com' + match_link

        session = HTMLSession()
 
        r = session.get(linked)

        allmatch2 = r.html.find("span.list-breadcrumb__item__in")
        partialresults = r.html.find(".list-details__item__partial")
        finalresults = r.html.find(".list-details__item__score")

        N = 3

        for match2, partialres, finalres in islice(zip(allmatch2, partialresults, finalresults), N):
            print(match2.text, partialres.text, finalres.text)
            yield {
                "match": match2.text,
                "htftresult": partialres.text,
                "result": finalres.text,                
            }
        
        
 
            
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(_get_rows(matchlink2))#.set_index("match")
    df2[['home','away']] = df2['match'].str.split("-",expand=True) 
    df2[['htresult','shresult']] = df2['htftresult'].str.split(",",expand=True) 
    df2['htresult'] = df2['htresult'].str.replace('(','')
    df2['shresult'] = df2['shresult'].str.replace(')','')
    df2['campionato'] = "Chi-A"
    df2['result'] = df2['result'].str.replace(':','-')
    df2['result'] = df2['result']
    colss2 = ['home', 'away', 'result']
    df2['uniquefield'] = df2[colss2].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
    df2 = df2[['home','away','htresult','shresult','result','campionato', 'uniquefield']]

    print(df2)


# determining the name of the file
file_name = 'BexDataHT.xlsx'
 
# saving the excel
df2.to_excel(file_name)
print('DataFrame is written to Excel File successfully.')
```

Comment: What's the error? What do you expect?  have you check the content of `allmatch2` ?

Comment: Some people would use a counter, and stop the loop when it reaches `n`.

Comment: @Ivan this code works but it iterate all, I'd like to iterate just, for example, the first 3 elemens

Comment: I would do as @tevemadar `for idx, match2, partialres, finalres in enumerate(zip(allmatch2, partialresults, finalresults))`

Comment: "I tried to use "itertools.islice" but without success." `isclice` is exactly the right tool for this job. If you encountered issues using it, please ask a specific question about those issues. See the [mre] help page on what we need to help you further.

Comment: Just slice one of the arrays, since `zip` stops at the end of the shortest list. For example, to iterate up to three times: `for a, b in zip(x[:3], y):`

Comment: this *is* a normal for loop, and `itertools.islice` is the right thing to use here. What **exactly** isn't working when you use it?

Comment: @Gaberocksall why wouldn't you just use `itertools.islice`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's much more to type than `[:3]`, so I wouldn't call it "just".

Comment: What do you mean by you "still get all values"? There are many different "values" in your code - of which exactly do you get all, how much are those, and how many do you expect? Please consider that a [mre] would be *far* more minimal than your current code: *Example* data should be hardcoded, and all parts that do work sufficiently should be removed to do nothing. Most likely, a MRE for this case should just have a small piece of hardcoded data and a generator function with the zip-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, where `N` is 3 for you (made a simple example):

```
from itertools import islice

N = 3

allmatch2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
partialresults = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
finalresults = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

for match2, partialres, finalres in islice(zip(allmatch2, partialresults, finalresults), N):
    print(match2, partialres, finalres)
```

output:

```
1 a 10
2 b 20
3 c 30
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I got this error: "NameError: name 'islice' is not defined. Did you mean: 'slice'?"

Comment: @Mapi i made a better example with the necessary import

Comment: @Mapi you can see [the doc here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it, I don't get any errors but I get all values. If I try your code alone, it's working, but with my code unfortunately no, and I don't know why

Comment: @Mapi can you show how you did it?

Comment: you can see my edit with my full code with your solution. You can try it, please

Answer (score -2):

> I'd like to iterate just, for example, the first 3 elemens

Use a counter.

```
for link in links:
    match_link = link.attrs['href']


    linked = 'https://www.betexplorer.com' + match_link

    session = HTMLSession()

    r = session.get(linked)

    allmatch2 = r.html.find("span.list-breadcrumb__item__in")
    partialresults = r.html.find(".list-details__item__partial")
    finalresults = r.html.find(".list-details__item__score")

    n = 3

    for match2, partialres, finalres in zip(allmatch2, partialresults, finalresults):
        match2.text
        partialres.text
        finalres.text
        print(match2.text)
        print(partialres.text)
        print(finalres.text)
        yield {
            "match": match2.text,
            "htftresult": partialres.text,
            "result": finalres.text,
            
        }

        n -= 1
        if n == 0:
            break
```

The `n = 3` in the middle and the last 3 lines.